# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '< '

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a stored procedure for a MSSQL 2008 R2 database.
The stored procedure should compare some values and return a bit/bool value.
Depending on a parameter (@PlatformCode), the procedure should choose the right check.

But I get an error, in the lines where I try to store my result in the output var.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckVersion 
    @PlatformCode nvarchar(4),
    @ClientVersion int,
    @ConfigId int = 1, 
    @Response bit OUTPUT 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @version int
    IF @PlatformCode = 'a' 
    BEGIN
        SET @version = (SELECT aVersion FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId)
        SET @Response = (@version <= @ClientVersion)
    END 
    IF @PlatformCode = 'i'
    BEGIN
        SET @version = (SELECT iVersion FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId)
        SET @Response = (@version <= @ClientVersion)
    END
END
GO
```

Is there maybe a better way, to return the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the CASE statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckVersion 
    @PlatformCode nvarchar(4),
    @ClientVersion int,
    @ConfigId int = 1, 
    @Response bit OUTPUT 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @version int
    IF @PlatformCode = 'a' 
    BEGIN
        SET @version = (SELECT aVersion FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId)
        SET @Response = CASE WHEN (@version <= @ClientVersion) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END 
    IF @PlatformCode = 'i'
    BEGIN
        SET @version = (SELECT iVersion FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId)
        SET @Response = CASE WHEN (@version <= @ClientVersion) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END
END
GO
```

better yet  you can do it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckVersion 
    @PlatformCode nvarchar(4),
    @ClientVersion int,
    @ConfigId int = 1, 
    @Response bit OUTPUT 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF @PlatformCode = 'a' 
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Response = CASE WHEN aVersion <= @ClientVersion  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId         
    END 
    IF @PlatformCode = 'i'
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Response = CASE WHEN iVersion <= @ClientVersion  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM AppConfigTable WHERE ConfigID = @ConfigId         
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, the better way is nice. In this way there is just line after the 'IF', so I can leave 'BEGIN' and 'END' off. Is it ok, or is it with both the 'beautifuller' code?

Comment: up to you you can either leave it or remove it. I prefer leaving it as it clearly shows where the IF logic applies to.

Comment: @BHuelse can you please mark the answer as accepted if you think this is the correct answer. : ) cheers

Comment: It is! I forget it, yesterday.